# Calculate recursively `log(log(log(134)))`

Tags: r

I want to recursively count the log cylces in my function

```
logCounter <- function(number) {
    k <- 0
    if(k>=0){
        k = k+1
    }
    result <- log(number)
    if (result > 1) {
        logCounter(result)
    } else {
        return(k)
    }
}

logCounter(123)#returns 3 because log(log(log(123))) < 1
```

However, my counter  `k` does not work as I would have inspected. Therefore I really would appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: You're almost there. First, take a look at what you have before the line with `result`. That code will result in `k` being `1` on every call on the function. You set `k` to 0, then you check if it is equal to zero (Which it is), then you increase it by 1, which get you k=1. Remember, a *new* value of `k` is created on every call, you don't store them in between calls. This is why, when you return k, you are always going to get `1`.

Comment: @nograpes Thx for your answer! However, I do not really know where to put `k` so that it is only once called...

Comment: The trick is to add something add each return, you don't need a `k` at all. That is a big hint. You should definitely review some examples of recursion.

Comment: @nograpes Thx for your answer! I also tried just using `k++` but that does not work in `R`. My problem is where to define `k = 0` once, so that I can use the value and just add it each cycle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this much more easily without calling the function recursively with a `while` loop:

```
logCounter <- function(number) {
    k <- 0
    result <- number
    while(result>1){
        k <- k + 1
        result <- log(result)
    }
    return(k)
}

> logCounter(123)
[1] 3
```

EDIT: If you need to use recursion, consider the `Recall` function:

```
logCounter <- function(number, iter=1) {
    if(log(number)>1)
        out <- Recall(log(number), iter+1)
    else
        out <- list(log(number),iter)
    return(out)
}

> logCounter(123)
[[1]]
[1] 0.4518085

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: @Thomas @nograpes Thx for your implementation. In fact, its not homework but a problem from a book(I want to learn `R`) and I really want to implement the function recursively...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Recall`. Try this:

```
logCounter <- function(number) {
  if (number <1) return(0) # A minor edit.
  result <- log(number)
  if (result > 1) return(logCounter(result)+1)
  return(1)
}
```

The key is to try to compose your function in a way that doesn't require storing intermediate results.